# (downgrade) apt install vlc 2.2.X on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, vlc

VLC 3 has broken `--start-time=` and I need this functionality, so would like to use 2.2.X

I've tried several things, such as these, but none work:

#### dpkg

```
dpkg -i vlc_2.2.7-1~deb8u1_amd64.deb
```

```
sudo dpkg -i vlc_2.2.7-1~deb8u1_amd64.deb
dpkg: warning: downgrading vlc from 3.0.8-3~16.04.york1 to 2.2.7-1~deb8u1
(Reading database ... 253418 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack vlc_2.2.7-1~deb8u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking vlc (2.2.7-1~deb8u1) over (3.0.8-3~16.04.york1) ...
Replaced by files in installed package vlc-plugin-skins2:amd64 (3.0.8-3~16.04.york1) ...
Replaced by files in installed package vlc-plugin-qt:amd64 (3.0.8-3~16.04.york1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of vlc:
 vlc depends on vlc-nox (= 2.2.7-1~deb8u1); however:
  Package vlc-nox is not installed.
 vlc depends on libavcodec56 (>= 6:11~beta1) | libavcodec-extra-56 (>= 6:11.9); however:
  Package libavcodec56 is not installed.
  Package libavcodec-extra-56 is not installed.
 vlc depends on libavutil54 (>= 6:11~beta1); however:
  Package libavutil54 is not installed.
 vlc depends on libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) | libgles1; however:
  Package libgles1-mesa is not installed.
  Package libgles1 is not installed.
 vlc depends on libvlccore8 (>= 2.2.0); however:
  Package libvlccore8 is not installed.
 vlc depends on libvncclient0 (>= 0.9.9); however:
  Package libvncclient0 is not installed.
 vlc depends on libxcb-composite0; however:
  Package libxcb-composite0 is not installed.
 vlc-plugin-skins2:amd64 (3.0.8-3~16.04.york1) breaks vlc (<< 3.0.0-1~) and is installed.
  Version of vlc to be configured is 2.2.7-1~deb8u1.
 vlc-plugin-qt:amd64 (3.0.8-3~16.04.york1) breaks vlc (<
dpkg: error processing package vlc (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.2) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20180209-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 vlc
```

#### apt

```
sudo apt install vlc-nox
```

Dependency hell (that I can't crack by following the instructions):

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.7-1~deb8u1) but 2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1 is to be installed
       Depends: libavcodec56 (>= 6:11~beta1) but it is not installable or
                libavcodec-extra-56 (>= 6:11.9) but it is not installable
       Depends: libavutil54 (>= 6:11~beta1) but it is not installable
       Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libgles1
       Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libvncclient0 (>= 0.9.9) but it is not installable
       Depends: libxcb-composite0 but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.2.7-1~deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 2.2.7-1~deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
 vlc-bin : Breaks: vlc-nox (< 3.0.0-1~) but 2.2.2+git20170721+r59033+56~ubuntu16.04.1 is to be installed
 vlc-nox : Depends: libdirectfb-1.2-9 but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libvcdinfo0 (>= 0.7.21) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
 vlc-plugin-qt : Breaks: vlc (< 3.0.0-1~) but 2.2.7-1~deb8u1 is to be installed
 vlc-plugin-skins2 : Breaks: vlc (< 3.0.0-1~) but 2.2.7-1~deb8u1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

#### build from source

I have a 0.2% success rate in building software from the source. I'm more likely to see flying pigs, so no point in trying that.

Comment: How did you get VLC 3 in the first place? [16.04 only has 2.2.2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/vlc). Some PPA? If so, purge that PPA.

Comment: 16.04 will be EOL in April, you should consider upgrading now, instead of fixing issues like this.

Comment: You have a mixsture of repositories. Please show the output of `apt-cache policy vlc vlc-nox vlc-plugin-qt`.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'm going to do both of these soon (I have 2 servers, I'll upgrade one to 20 LTS, and temporarily install vlc 2 on the other.